# Getting a connection refused error when trying to use telnet and not sure why

Tags: telnet

I am trying to send an email to my little brother from a fake address as a prank, but I am having some trouble with telnet, and I can't figure out why it's not working.  I'm using terminal on a Mac, but I can't imagine it's much different.  Here's what I've typed in so far.

```
*omitted*:~ *omitted*$ nslookup
> set type=mx
> google.com
Server:     172.30.31.252
Address:    172.30.31.252#53

Non-authoritative answer:
google.com  mail exchanger = 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com  mail exchanger = 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com  mail exchanger = 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com  mail exchanger = 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com  mail exchanger = 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.

... (some other stuff omitted)

*omitted*:~ *omitted*$ telnet aspmx.l.google.com 25
Trying 74.125.140.26...
telnet: connect to address 74.125.140.26: Connection refused
Trying 2607:f8b0:4002:c04::1b...
telnet: connect to address 2607:f8b0:4002:c04::1b: No route to host
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Unfortunately, I have completely exhausted my ideas for what could be going wrong here.

I made sure I don't have my firewall on.

I tried `sudo pico inetd.conf`, but the file is completely blank - not sure where else I would find telnet on my computer.

The backlog of queued inbound connection requests definitely isn't full because I've gotten the same error over and over again.

Does anyone have suggestions for how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because I needed to use a much higher port number. 25 was blocked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send from a fake email, the easiest way is to apply for a new email address